# nitrous.io environment variables for check develop or production server

Tags: nitrousio

In my configuration files, I use environment variables for check if is a develop or production server. 
For example: OpenShitf have variables like OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR, etc.

Does Nitrous.io have some default environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Nitrous is a fairly standard linux install.  So it has a lot of environment variables by default.  Just type `set` and the shell and you will see a list.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
```